# extract layers by name from DXF file to multiple destination files using ogr2ogr command line

Tags: layers, kml, ogr2ogr, dxf, extract

Is this possible to extract layers of a DXF file into multiple files using ogr2ogr command line ?

Let us say my DXF file consists of 2 layers : ROAD and HOME.

I want my output to be some kml files.

So I run the following command :

```
ogr2ogr -f "KML" plan.kml plan.dxf -s_srs EPSG:27562 -t_srs EPSG:4326
```

Which works very well.

**QUESTION**

But how can I specify I want multiples files in output ? Or should I programmatically code this using a loop and extract each layer individually ?

Answer (score 1):

To address this issue, `ogr2ogr` command line does not provide out of the box function to quickly create multiple output (for each layer) for the input file.

**SOLUTION**

I came up with a solution (using PHP in my case) which is split in 2 steps :

1. Use `ogrinfo` to get all the layers
2. Retrieve all the layer, and for each layer use `ogr2ogr`

**DETAIL**

I first launch `ogrinfo plan.dxf -sql "SELECT DISTINCT Layer FROM entities"` (all my dxf files begin with `entities` element wrapper). You will need to extract only the name of the layers (in php, for each lines, I used the following regex : `/=\s([\w|\s]+)$/u`, `u` flag because sometimes my layers names can contain accents).

Then, once I have my array of layers, for each layers I apply this command : `ogr2ogr -f "KML" <layer_name>-fond.kml fond.dxf -s_srs EPSG:27562 EPSG:4326 -where "Layer='<layer_name>'"`, with `<layer_name>` to be replaced by the name of the current layer name in your loop.

To inject the layer name, I used PHP string injection :

```
exec("ogr2ogr -f \"KML\" $layerName-fond.kml fond.dxf -s_srs EPSG:27562 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -where \"Layer='$layerName'\"");
```